# Falla en generar archivo xls desde evento de boton Spring MVC

Tags: java, mvc, spring

Buen día.
Tengo un proyecto web y uso java con spring MVC. En un evento de onClick, debe generarse un reporte en un archivo xls. El problema es que no lo hace si uso Google Chrome, pero si lo hace con Edge o Firefox.

¿Cuál podría ser una posible solución para que funcione tambíen con Chrome?

*Uso la clase File con createNewFile().
*Para crear el libro usando el objeto HSSFWorkbook.
*FileOutputStream para inicializar el flujo de datos.
* y la clase Sheet para crear la nueva hoja de trabajo.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: y que error te da cuando usas chrome?

Comment: Faltan detalles: ¿cómo devuelves el fichero para descargarlo? Mostrar el código del controlador ayudaría

Comment: El error estuvo en el front .. desde el jsp .. una instrucción de: validNavigation = false bloqueaba la pagina de descarga del archivo ... Muchas gracias por su aportación. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error estuvo en el front .. desde el jsp que usé para el evento del botón .. una instrucción de: validNavigation = false, bloqueaba la pagina de descarga del archivo ...

Muchas gracias por su aportación. Saludos